Interrupting a thread from ShutdownHook doesn't close resources
I have following code with a try-with-resources which creates two resources and it works fine:
public class SimpleResourceExample {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try (var resource1 = new Resource(1);
             var resource2 = new Resource(2)) {
            System.out.println("Using "+resource1 +" and "+resource2);
            Thread.sleep(20 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private record Resource(int id) implements AutoCloseable {
        @Override
        public void close() {
            System.out.println("Closing resource "+id);
        }
    }
}

So when I run it I get following output (in 20 seconds):
Using Resource[id=1] and Resource[id=2]
Closing resource 2
Closing resource 1

Process finished with exit code 0

And when I add below code (in main(), just before try-with-resources), to interrupt the thread, it also works fine:
        var t = Thread.currentThread();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
                t.interrupt();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }).start();

So this new thread interrupts the main thread after 10 seconds and the resources are also closed, with below output:
Using Resource[id=1] and Resource[id=2]
Closing resource 2
Closing resource 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
    at ....

Process finished with exit code 1


(stack trace omitted for brevity)
But when I introduce a shutdown-hook with below code:
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Shutting down");
            t.interrupt();
        }));

And trigger it with this command:
kill -15 <PID> 

I get following output:
Using Resource[id=1] and Resource[id=2]
Shutting down

Process finished with exit code 143 (interrupted by signal 15:SIGTERM)

This means it gets the signal and stops the application. And I think it also sends the interrupt to the main thread, but it doesn't close resources.
Does anybody know why this happens and how to ensure the resources are closed?
Thanks.

Are you sure the resources aren't being closed?  It could be that the output is being buffered and doesn't get printed on the screen.  Any other circumstance that you are having issues with?

This triggered me to think that perhaps the thread started from ShutdownHook is not waiting long enough for the println() to be visible and the application is closing before printing these lines to the console. When I added t.join() it behaves as I expected. I'll add that as an answer here.

The comment from u/markspace triggered me to think that perhaps the thread started from the ShutdownHook is not waiting long enough to show the println() printing those lines.
So I added t.join() as below and it worked.
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Shutting down");
            t.interrupt();
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }));

This way we ensure that we wait for the main thread to terminate and now the output is:
Using Resource[id=1] and Resource[id=2]
Shutting down
Closing resource 2
Closing resource 1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
...

Process finished with exit code 143 (interrupted by signal 15:SIGTERM)

(Again stack-trace omitted for brevity.)
So here I see that the Resource-s are getting close()-ed.
